# How to know if the app is running at local or on server? (R Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I test my app on my laptop, and then deploy it to shinyapps server.
Before deploying, I need to remove the statement setting the path, e.g.,

```
setwd('/Users/MrY/OneDrive/Data')
```

Is there a way the code can find out if it's running locally or on server, so that it will be like:

```
if (isLocal()) {
       setwd('/Users/MrY/OneDrive/Data')
}
```

---

A trivial sample code (it will fail on server if `setwd` isn't removed):

server.R

```
library(shiny)

setwd('/Users/Yuji/OneDrive/Data/TownState')  

data = 'data1.csv'  # to test, using an empty .csv file

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Click the button"),

    sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
    ),
    mainPanel(

    )
))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard way to do this in Shiny is with: `Sys.getenv('SHINY_PORT')`. You could write something like:

```
is_local <- Sys.getenv('SHINY_PORT') == ""
```

Comment: Assuming you don't change your port variable yourself, which is unlikely.  Just wondering though, it that officially better /more reliable than looking at the actual session hostname or port?  Did someone on the Shiny team say this is the best way?

Comment: [Yep](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/Sys.getenv/shiny-discuss/JfvjuKdLssI/Ac86v7toJv8J)

Answer (score 8):

EDIT 2020: There still is no official way to do this, but I would opt for Yihui's method of `is_local <- Sys.getenv('SHINY_PORT') == ""`

---

I don't know if this is the proper way or not, but you could look at the host using `session$clientData$url_hostname`. When you run it locally, unless you specifically change the host, it will be `127.0.0.1` and I'm guessing on shinyapps it'll be something like `shinyapps.io`.  Sample code

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      if (session$clientData$url_hostname == "127.0.0.1") {
        setwd(...)
      }
    })
  }
))
```

Something of that sort should work, though I can't vouch for whether or not it's the best solution

Comment: i guess this line will be run after all global.R has been loaded right? so might be too late for stuff that need to happen right at the launch of the app ?

Comment: Correct, global runs before this. This answer is 4 years old, I have seen the shiny source code since then and I now know that the way shiny does it is by setting an environment variable, though I don't remember what it's called!

Comment: What's the best way to do it now in 2020 ? I am curious to know about this too.

Comment: There's still no official way, but I use Yihui's suggesetion. `is_local <- Sys.getenv('SHINY_PORT') == ""`

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve the host name and query that. The computers should have different host names.

```
    library(R.utils)
    hname <- System$getHostname()
```

yields

```
           nodename 
"mikes-air-3.wisedom.local"
```